# How can I use PL/pgSQL over a JDBC connection?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql

I am writing a database using flyway and maven to apply migration scripts to a Postgres 11 database.

I'd like to be able to write statements in PL/pgSQL that flyway can run over its JDBC connection, just like regular ansi SQL.

Eg,

```
--some regular sql statements
create table test(id bigint);
select * from test;
--etc

--switch to plpgsql
language plpgsql;
--some plpgsql code goes here
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed PL/pgSQL in SQL using a `DO` statement:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
   ...
BEGIN
   ...
END;
$$;
```